# Что пишется при отрицании в данном предложении: НЕ или НИ?

Tags: не-или-ни

*Тут нельзя ничего ни переделать, ни отнять, ни добавить.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Тут нельзя ничего **ни** переделать, **ни** отнять, **ни** добавить.*

НИ — это усилительная частица, НЕ — отрицательная.
НИ пишется при отрицательном сказуемом или в деепричастном обороте, усиливая отрицание, которое выражено словами **не, нет, нельзя** (при этом отрицание может только подразумеваться).
*Ночь проходит, **нет** дороги **ни** вперед и **ни** назад. На небе **ни** облачка (нет).

Шёл, **не** видя **ни** дороги, **ни** прохожих.*

Частица **ни** усиливает смысл, поэтому может быть заменена союзом **и** или просто опущена:
Ночь проходит, дороги вперед и назад нет.
Тут ничего нельзя переделать, отнять, добавить.
[НЕ или НИ?](http://www.hi-edu.ru/CentrDovusBooks/Intensive/47.pdf)

*Все предопределено судьбой, и тут ничего нельзя ни убавить, ни прибавить* (Конфуций).